# How to add the user entered values dynamically in same page without redirecting in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I've created *four text boxes*(`val1, val2, val3, total`) in a web form. If user enters a value of `20` in `textbox1` the "`total`" should be `20`, if user enters second value as `30` then `total` should be `50`.. but should not use button redirect method. the answers should display in same page?? Can any one provide me the code in asp.net. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ajax with jquery to achieve your gaol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do this calculations and show the result on the page. Use either OnClientClick method of button or on Loosing focus on textbox. I am assuming you dont want to store the result on server/database. If you need to get this calculations done on server side, use ajax call for the same. Read about Jquery/Ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Javascript, just asp.net i suggest you to create Label `LblResult`, when you click add this code to your delegate.

Note : Add validators to your asp.net text box

```
LblResult.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Tbx1.Text.Trim()) + 
Convert.ToInt32(Tbx2.Text.Trim()) +
Convert.ToInt32(Tbx3.Text.Trim()) + 
Convert.ToInt32(Tbx4.Text.Trim());
```